Laplacian of 1/r equals zero?
i was reading and suddenly i saw the expression:
$$
\nabla^2 \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) = 0
$$
where $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} $
i do not understand how does it becomes zero with $ \frac{1}{r} $ or with the cartesian expression.
it is from a seismic theory book

Where is your work?

Yes, $\nabla^{2}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$ is not always 0. Could you provide more context to this equation?

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785464/42969

it was from a seismic theory book, as i show in the picture
